# If the set of all linear maps is itself a vector space, then what is its basis and dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, we learn about linear mappings and it is an easy proof that the set of all linear maps is itself a vector space over the same field. But if it's a vector space how would one go about figuring out what a basis for the set of linear maps are? To be more specific we can take the set of all linear map from R^3 to R^2 over the field R.

Comment: Are you familiar with tensor products?

Comment: Linear maps with which domain and which codomain? T

Answer (score 2):

A bit more basic: Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $B_V$ and $B_W$ be bases of these vector spaces. Then each linear map $L:V\longrightarrow W$ can be uniquely written as
$$\begin{align}L\left(\sum_{x\in B_V} a_x x\right)&=\sum_{x\in B_V}a_x L(x)\\
&=\sum_{x\in B_V}a_x\sum_{y\in B_W}b_y y\\
&=\sum_{x\in B_V}\sum_{y\in B_W}a_xb_y y\end{align}$$
The coefficients $c_{xy}:=a_x b_y$ uniquely determine the function. That's the idea of the matrix representation of a linear map. Those coefficients are the matrix entries in the finite dimensional case. Now let's define the linear maps $L_{xy}:V\longrightarrow W$ which map $x\in B_V$ to $y\in B_W$ and map every other element of $B_V$ to $0$. We can see that using the coefficients from above, we can write $L=\sum_{x\in B_V}\sum_{y\in B_w} c_{xy}L_{xy}$., and there is only one way to do so. That means, the maps $L_{xy}$ are a basis of the space of linear maps $V\longrightarrow W$. There is exactly one such map for each combination of vectors in $B_V$ and $B_W$, that is, one for each element of $B_V\times B_W$. So the dimension is the cardinality of this product. In the finite dimensional case, that's the product of the cardinalities of $B_V$ and $B_W$, so the product of the dimensions of $V$ and $W$.

So that's the takeaway: if $\dim V=n,\dim W=m$, then $\dim\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)=nm$.